# Vaadin TextField input prompt gets removed when focused

Tags: java, vaadin

If I set a placeholder text in an HTML input element, the placeholder text is visible even when the input field is focused. It only gets removed when I type something in the field.

But, in vaadin, if I set an input prompt to a TextField by calling `setInputPrompt()`, the input prompt gets disappeared as soon as the field gets focus. To view the input prompt again, user has to focus out from TextField.

This is problematic since when a window loads, if I set the initial focus to a TextField, the input prompt is not visible. User has to focus out from the field to see the prompt.

I know that I can use a javascript call to set the placeholder instead of using `setInputPrompt()`. But, are there any better way to do this?

Comment: I just tried this, created a new project in Vaadin 7.7.5, put a setInputPrompt on a TextField, but the input prompt always stays. Even when I focus in, type text, focus out, focus back in, remove the text, focus out - the input prompt becomes visible again. Perhaps you could show some source, because I don't think what you are describing is default behaviour

Comment: @arnehehe, just check TextField in vaadin sampler https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/text-input/text-field. Initially input prompt `Write something` is shown in TextField, and as soon as you click on it, input prompt disappears.